# exception handling in camel - choice block in doTry

Tags: apache-camel

In the following code, could anyone please explain what choice block does in doTry and why it doesn't catch RuntimeCamelException?

```
<doTry>
            <process ref="msgProcessor" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>"false" == "true" &amp;&amp; ${exchangeProperty.status} == ${ref:SUCCESS}</simple>
                    <process ref="queryProcessor" />
                </when>
            </choice>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>"false" == "true" &amp;&amp; ${exchangeProperty.status} == ${ref:SUCCESS}</simple>
                    <process ref="compareProcessor" />
                </when>
            </choice>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException</exception>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
```

I'm still getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Scanner aborted because of an IOException!
at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter$SplitterIterable$1.hasNext(Splitter.java:171)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:268)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:225)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:104)
```

Comment: I am having similar issues. It looks like .doTry() and .choice() do not play well together.

Answer (score 0):

My guess at first look is that your exception is not being handled by the try catch and is being propagated back up to the route's error handling.

Try adding some processing when you discover the error:
- set handled = true
- drop a custom log
- stop to end processing on the exchange.

That will make it really easy to confirm if your error handler is being called.